# asyncio Queue.get delay

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, python-asyncio

I have the following code:

```
import asyncio
import threading
import time

q = asyncio.Queue()

async def ping():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(10)
        print("ping")

async def rcv():
    while True:
        item = await q.get()
        print("got item")

async def run():
    tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(ping()), asyncio.ensure_future(rcv())]
    await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when="FIRST_EXCEPTION")

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

def run_loop():
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(run())

threading.Thread(target=run_loop).start()

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    q.put_nowait("item")
    print("item added")
```

I expected that every 2 seconds (each time item is added to the queue), I'll see the output:

```
item added
sleeping 2 seconds
got item
```

and every 10 seconds I'll also see `ping`.

However, this is the output I get (repeating):

```
sleeping 2 seconds
item added
sleeping 2 seconds
item added
sleeping 2 seconds
item added
sleeping 2 seconds
item added
sleeping 2 seconds
got item
got item
got item
got item
ping
item added
sleeping 2 seconds
...
```

It seems as if the part `item = await q.get()` wait also for `asyncio.sleep(10)` from the `ping` function.

What did I miss? and how can I fix the code so I'll get the expected output?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What did I miss? and how can I fix the code so I'll get the expected output?

Since you are running the event loop in a separate thread, you need to change `q.put_nowait("item")` to:

```
loop.call_soon_threadsafe(q.put_nowait, "item")
```

The reason is that asyncio code is (intentionally) not thread-safe, so using `put_nowait` doesn't notify the event loop that a new item was enqueued.

Comment: can you also use put(), without nowait, in a similar way to avoid full queue exceptions

Comment: @cIph3r The OP's queue is unbounded, so the issue never arose. You can't pass `q.put` to `call_soon_threadsafe` accepts a sync function, and `Queue.put` is async. But you can use `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` instead: `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(q.put("item"), loop).result()`. `run_coroutine_threadsafe` returns a `concurrent.futures.Future` (not to be confused with asyncio Future) whose `result()` method waits for the underlying coroutine to finish, i.e. in this case for `put` to actually find a free slot in the queue.

Comment: Note that failing to wait for the result will defeat the purpose of the bounded queue, as it will cause tasks to accumulate in the event loop without bounds, and fail to provide the intended backpressure.